# How find openbook Id

Tags: token, liquiditypool

I created an openBook on Raydium and accidentally refreshed the page where can I find this ID to create a pool?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.